# Data Service using EF - is it possible to use WebGet method which returns a custom type?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

In my project I use Data Service which use EF. Now I have a custom class which I also want to expose through my Data Service, but I can't make it work, it's seems like it is impossible to mix custom types and EF in single Data Service. Any suggestions?

Looks like it doesn't find some info in meta-data.

**Error:**

> The server encountered an error
>   processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Unable to load metadata
>   for return type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ITS.NetProject.Model.CustomEnty]'
>   of method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ITS.NetProject.Model.CustomEnty]
>   GetCustomEnties()'.'. See server logs
>   for more details. The exception stack
>   trace is:....

**Code:**

```
   [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
        public class ITSServiceOData : DataService<ITSEntities>
        {
            public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
            {

                config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);

                config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetCustomEnties",                
    ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);

                config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
            }


            [WebGet]
            public IQueryable<CustomEnty> GetCustomEnties()
            {
                return from e in this.CurrentDataSource.CustomEnties select e;

            }

        }

///Here it is my model definition

namespace ITS.NetProject.Model
{
    partial class ITSEntities
    {
        public IQueryable<CustomEnty> CustomEnties 
        {
            get
            {
                return ...
            }
        }
    }

//Company, Equipment, Owner are EF entity classes
    [DataServiceKey("Id")]
    public class CustomEnty
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public Subject Company { get; set; }

        public Subject Equipment { get; set; }

        public Subject Owner { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `CustomEntry` part of the Entity framework model?

Comment: Not it's just custom class defined inside the namespace of EF model, but doesn't belong it.

Answer (score 1):

No, Data Services do not support that scenario. You can add your custom type to your Entity Fx model, but that is far from ideal...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm free rider
 - Put the class and Object in the model and do it  properly. As per advice above.
 - or Make separate simple model. Use same connection string.

or for that nasty hack...

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmdText, parameters);
```

when no one is looking at beer oClock. :-)